# JDBC connection to BigQuery with DDL statements

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, ddl

I'm looking for a JDBC driver for Google Bigquery that also has DDL capabilities such as drop/create table.

I see that the Simba and Star-schema drivers don't have such a capability. Is anyone aware of drivers that do?

Comment: From the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or **find** a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: The Simba drivers now support DDL: ODBC [since v2.1.11](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/release-notes.txt) (2018-05-31) and JDBC [since v1.1.6](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/jdbc/release-notes.txt) (2018-04-27).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't support DDL at all. The options that are available to you will depend on what's generating your DDL. If it's totally under your control, you can implement these operations using the REST API directly, or using an existing client that wraps the API. You could in theory write your own JDBC driver that parses all queries, intercepts DDL, and implements it using the REST API ... but that would be painful and error-prone. It's not clear whether Google plan on supporting DDL at some point.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct since 1) BigQuery supports DDL and 2) the Simba driver also now supports DDL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659048/jdbc-connection-to-bigquery-with-ddl-statements#comment94081777_41659048